# Как расположить блоки вокруг центральной картинки?

Tags: вёрстка

Есть вот такой макет, где пять блоков текста расположены по кругу, а центре имеется картинка. С подобной структурой сталкиваюсь впервые, есть какая-то схема вёрстки такого рода вещей? Мне на ум приходит только
position: absolute, причём как на блоки, так и остальные элементы дизайна (иконки, полосочки эти и тд). Как быть с этими полосочками
(тупо вырезать в виде картинки или как-то бордером их выводить)? Как быть с иконками, как быть с реализацией этих блоков вокруг картинки? Можно ли их сделать не через position: absolute, а как-то более правильно?

[image: макет с блоками текста]

Comment: Верстка с postition: absolute кажется сдесь единственно верным выходом

Comment: Можно попробывать flex или float. Линии сделать через псевдоелементы + transform: rotate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень многое зависит от требований, должна ли эта верстка быть адаптивной, как должны вести себя элементы при разных разрешениях окна, и т.д?

Если речь не идет про адаптивную верстку, то макет вполне себе делится на стандартные блоки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основная загвозка заключается именно в нижних подчеркиваниях заголовков, к сожалению, я не могу с ходу дать классный ответ, как нижнее подчеркивание вывести к центру за пределы блоков, точнее это требует просто детального внимания. Однако общий смысл моего варианта - вы засовываете центральную картинку и все линии(подчеркивания) (или подчеркивания не засовываете в изображение, а действительно используете :after :before с position:absolute и поворотами) в бекграунд главного блока. А в этом блоке создаете дочерние блоки по тому же принципу, что и на скриншоте.

Answer (score 0):

Для полосок используй `::after` или `::before`. Сами полоски сделай png или если есть возможность svg. Я бы сделал спрайт из png. Потом ставим их в фон `::after` или `::before`. И позиционируем. + в том что при изменении размера блока полоски будут там где тег с текстом. А в мобильной и планшетной версии их можно просто скрыть. Что бы позиционировать в отношении блока заголовка пропиши ему `position relative`